# How do you perform basic statistical analysis on a Binary Dataset?

Tags: python, data-mining, statistics, bigdata

I have never worked with a Binary dataset (1 and 0) (True or False) so I'm unsure what kind of  statistical tests I should run to draw up simple conclusions.

I'm doing a data science project and the company wants to know/understand what **features/characteristics** are important to decide whether or not a customer will renew their lease (last column in Graph). They want me to just perform basic/simple probability and statistical analysis on the dataset.

I'm working in a Juypter notebook (pandas, seaborm, numpy, matplotlib, sklearn). I would appreciate it if someone could help lead me in a direction to what kind of simple analysis I can run on binary data.

Heres a **sample** of the table:

| ID | Age 20-29 | Age 30-39 | Age 40-49 | Age 50 > | Lease Length < 1 year | Lease Length 1-2 Years | Lease Length > 3 Years | Late Payment | No Fine Violations | Credit Score Below 600 | Renews |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 312 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 313 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 314 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 315 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |

Comment: Not sure about `basic/simple probability and statistical analysis` in terms of understanding what features drive the outcome, but what you can do is to fit simple model (something like `DecisionTrees`) and then do feature explanation, either using native feature importance or something like `shap` which nice visuals and a lot of explanation capabilities. Not sure in terms of purely binary data, but I would definitely give it a try. link -  https://github.com/slundberg/shap

Comment: you can try correlation (or even categorical correlation) between random variables (so one can see how much a certain feature is correlated with desired outcome). For example simple inspection shows that younger age groups renew the plan (highly correlated to desired outcome)